# Java installation in mac

Tags: java, macos

I am new to mac. Running the `javac` / `java -version` command yields negative result. However, I do see java under system preferences. I have not installed JDK/JRE yet. On clicking the java icon, under update, it shows that the system has the recommended version of java. `Java 8 update 144`. What is the java icon doing under system preferences when I have not installed JDK/JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `JRE`, which comes along with OS by default. I'm not sure, how did you executed `java -version` command. In my case, I get proper information about installed `JRE`.

[image]

You probably need to check your `User` and `System` variable under `Java`

[image]

Also, it is obvious to get error when executing `javac` without installing `JDK`.

Comment: I have this path under User : /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java. Is this not correct

Comment: This seems to be corrected. But, question is, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I had to start with installing JDK. But I stumbled upon the JRE which you pointed out. Hence I am curious why java -version is not throwing the expected result.

Comment: Because, that tells the java runtime version. In other word, what version of java application can be supported on this machine.

Comment: Sorry for dragging this bit longer. But what I mean is according to your info - JRE was already there in the system (as the User path showed up in the settings). If so then why java -version command failed. That is my doubt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152864/discussion-between-starhunter-and-ravi).

Comment: I had to install JDK upon which the commands are working. Thanks